# How can I access scope.postresult value in javascript written in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, disqus

I have below controller.js code where in I am getting "postresult" value.

```
$scope.open= function(post) {
           $scope.postresult = post;
}
```

In below HTML code, where I am loading DISQUS thread, I need to access "postresult" object, how can I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pid = '{{postresult.id}}';
    var pid1 = 'postresult.id';

    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'a2b'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
    var disqus_identifier =  '{{postresult.id}}' ;
    var disqus_title = '{{postresult.postText}}';
    var disqus_url = 'http://pingle.com:8080/ngdemo/{{postresult.id}}';

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();

    var reset = function (postresult.id, http://pingle.com:8080/ngdemo/{{postresult.id}}, postresult.postText, en) {
        DISQUS.reset({
            reload: true,
            config: function () {
                this.page.identifier = newIdentifier;
                this.page.url = newUrl;
                this.page.title = newTitle;
                this.language = newLanguage;
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put it on the global window object using the `$window` service

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $window.postresult = 0;

    $scope.change = function() {
       $window.postresult++;  
    }
});
```

then you can access it from any javascript with `window.postresult`

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    window.$('#output').text(window.postresult);
},100);
```

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sj69pvrpHGk2gFl4xDJZ?p=preview

Comment: ReferenceError: $window is not defined is the issue coming and will it work if I am defining $window.postresult = post; in my controller.js and reading this in script defined in HTML???

Comment: $window error went away, but when the same window.postresult I am accesing in html which is defined HTML , value is not reaching there

Comment: `$window` is an Angular service which you should pass in as a parameter to your controller function (dependency injection), `window` is the global object in the browser. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: Is your problem solved? Is there something not clear?